# Using COUNTIF in Excel when you need to manipulate text

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

The problem is this: I have a column full of nouns. These nouns could be something like: "Doctor", "doctor" or "DOCTOR " (with a space at the end).
Clearly I need to normalize those records before using `COUNTIF`. Rigth now I'm just using a new column "in the middle" in which I normalize the data and then I use COUNTIF on those normalized data.

I'm doing this because I can't understand how I can normalize the range taken for COUNTIF as first argumenti. Is it possibile to apply functions to the first argument? Or is there a more suitable function I can use in this case?

I have at home the 2007 and at the office 2010 so you can aim for both version.

**Requested example:**

Column A has:

```
"Doctor "
"doctor"
"  doctoR"
"fireman"
```

I need to do something like **COUNTIF( *NORMALIZE(A1:A4)* ; "doctor" )** because "  Doctor" will not match "doctor" because of the space. Right now I'm doing **NORMALIZE(A1:A4)** in B1:B4 and then **COUNTIF( B1:B4; "doctor")**

NORMALIZE is something I just inventend, not a real function of course.

Comment: can you explain with some example with input and expected output?

Comment: edited with an example.

Comment: So you mean if you do countif(A1:A4, "doctor"), your expected output should be 3 or 1?

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem. My expected output is 3, and 3 I have. I'm just asking if there's a way to normalize the range inside the COUNTIF and not using two steps in the process.

Comment: Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*doctor*")
```

**OR**

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A4,"*doctor*")
```

### OUTPUT

```
3
```

Comment: If I have something like "University     professor" should I use the wildcard in the middle? Does it accept + like for regexp,like "University +professor"? (1 or more). I do not have backtick on my kb. It should be 4 spaces between University and professor.

Comment: @dierre: `+` won't do. If you set `University*professor`, you get total count. And if you want specifically to check 4 spaces between University and professor then your formula can be `University    professor`

Comment: ok but that will check also "Universityprofessor" right?

Comment: @dierre: yes, it will count this one too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of nouns and variations, than you can use some addition in your formula and capture all the possible variations (capitalization shouldn't matter, but spaces does):

=COUNTIF(A2:A4,"doctor")+COUNTIF(A2:A4,"doctor ")+COUNTIF(A2:A4," doctor")

Using a helper column or column "in the middle" is also a good way (and sometimes a necessary way) to manage shaping the data for analysis.  Often they can help keep your formulas from getting too complex.